# Bigger operator (>) shows up when I enter arguments in terminal

Tags: command-line

I found that it happens because it splits entered arguments. But I am creating a program that encrypts string and it encrypted "test" as `|m{|`. But when I switch to decryption mode that thing happens. Any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `>` comes from `bash`'s `$PS2` variable. `man bash` says:

```
PS2    The value of this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and used as the secondary prompt string.  The default is ``> ''.
```

I often see `>` when I have an unmatched quote (`"`) or apostrophe (`'`), or some other input that `bash` views as incomplete.

Comment: Is there any way to input "|m{|" (without quotes) into terminal ?

Comment: @StelTeam I believe terminal is waiting for you to enter `}`. What's wrong if it is enter within double quotes? I think it is just a filename. Isn't it?

Comment: @Kulfy The string |m{| is the encrypted version of "test". so the program must take |m{| as an argument in order to decrypt it as "test"

Comment: ... if you enter `"|m{|"` `'|m{|'` in the shell as an argument to your program, your program will not see the quotes (they will simply prevent the shell from trying to interpret the sequence)

Comment: @StelTeam  Without quotes `|` will be treated as pipe symbol and `{` as start of compound command, therefore the shell will treat it as part of its syntax and consider the line you entered incomplete. That's what `>` signifies.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Okay. So I cant enter that string to terminal? Is there any way?

Comment: @StelTeam You could enter  hex value for the characters , such as `$'\7b'` for `{`, but otherwise - no.  Quoting is a necessity in this case.   If you are OK with using `read` command to prompt user for string, such as `read -p "Enter encrypted string:" var_to_store`  and then use `$var_to_store` - then it can work. Shell won't treat characters specially with `read`. But when you type it as `./mycommand.sh arg1` , then arg1 has to follow shell rules

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy if you can post it as answer I can access it. Thank you!